# Скрытие элементов VK

Tags: javascript, css, вконтакте

В вк сообщения представлены такими блоками

[image: так выглядят сообщения в беседе]

Как можно скрывать целиком блоки с сообщениями от конкретного ID? Что-то вроде черного списка внутри беседы, полный игнор определенного человека.

Answer (score 1):

```
[data-peer="305076615"] {
    display: none;
}
```